# How to redirect cout and cin?

Tags: c++, cout, cin

I'm executing my program with the following command:
`./myProgram -i test.in -o test.out`

Both files are legal and exist.

```
// run all over the arguments and set the cin and cout if needed
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i= i+2)
{
    int j = i+1;

    // loop over each pairs of arguments
    do
    {
        // set cin
        if(argv[i] == "-i")
        {
            static std :: ifstream s_inF(argv[j]);
            std :: cin.rdbuf(s_inF.rdbuf());
            break;
        }

        //set cout
        if(argv[i] == "-o")
        {
            std::ofstream out(argv[j]);
            std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
            break;
        }

        // in order to search for the other case
        // (example:X.out -i)
        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
    }while(i>j);
}
```

I wrote this block in `main` in order to redirect `cin` and `cout` according to `char **argv`.
`cin` works just fine but `cout` does not.
When I take it like that it works:

```
// run all over the arguments and set the cin and cout if needed
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i= i+2)
{
    int j = i+1;

    // loop over each pairs of arguments
    do
    {
        // set cin
        if(argv[i] == "-i")
        {
            static std :: ifstream s_inF(argv[j]);
          std :: cin.rdbuf(s_inF.rdbuf());
          break;
        }

        //set cout
        if(argv[i] == "-o")
            break;

        // in order to search for the other case
        // (example:X.out -i)
        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
    }while(i>j);
}

std::ofstream out(argv[4]);
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: I forgot the static!!!!!!!!! that is why  sorry but could you tell me why we need to set the cin and cout in the main and not in other function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stream whose stream buffer you installed to `std::cout` gets destructed right after installing the stream buffer:

```
std::ofstream out(argv[j]);
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
```

The first line needs to read

```
static std::ofstream out(argv[j]);
```

There may be other errors but this is the one I spotted.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because you need j to be `i+1` for the redirecting of the output to work. Give it a try - what happens if you first pass the `-o` and then the `-i` in the first sample?

Change this:

```
        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
```

To this:

```
        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp + 1;
```

You will also have to work on the while condition.

By the way why do you need `j` at all? You can do it only with i and than use i+1 for the redirection. I believe this will also make the code easier to understand.

Comment: You mean why does it work? Well because the index of the argument used for the output there is fixed to 4, while in your previous code it will have a different value. You may also try to debug your code to understand better what I mean.